# Can't increase upload_max_filesize in a Wordpress LAMP stack

Tags: apache-http-server, php, wordpress, lamp, php.ini

I've been trying to increase the maximum upload size of my Wordpress instance, and I've already tried all methods mentioned in the results I get when searching this issue.

I've tried changing the php.ini file, the .htaccess, the wp-config.php, etc. and it's still doesn't change from 2MB.

This might be important:
If I run `php -i` and find the upload_max_filesize, it shows up with the increased value, but when I print a `phpinfo();`, it displays the default 2MB, even though both display the same path in "Loaded Configuration File".

Do you have any idea on what I'm missing? It's getting very frustrating.
Thanks in advance

Comment: When you changed your `php.ini` file did you restart the Apache process?

Comment: What are your `php.ini` values for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`?

Comment: @Kinnectus I did restart. `upload_max_filesize` is 256M and `post_max_size` is 256M also

Comment: Also, you say you changed `php.ini` yet when you run `phpinfo` it doesn't show the updated value. As MrNiceGuy points out it could be permissions on the file OR, if you look at the `phpinfo` output, you may have edited the wrong file? Make sure the file is the one identified in `phpinfo`...

Comment: Have you checked in the WordPress dashboard, Settings, the value of “Max upload file size”? You may also change it here.

Comment: @harrymc I do not have that option in my Wordpress v5.0.3 Settings

Answer (score 2):

So you checked `phpinfo()` for `Loaded Configuration File`, made the appropriate changed to `memory_limit`, `post_max_size`, and `upload_max_filesize`, then restarted Apache and... *nothing changed*.

Try comparing the outputs of:

`php -i | grep -E "Loaded Configuration File|memory_limit|post_max_size|upload_max_filesize"`

and

`lynx -dump (URL of phpinfo.php) | grep -E "Loaded Configuration File|memory_limit|post_max_size|upload_max_filesize"`

You may find that `phpinfo()` and `php -i` are loading different configuration files, and that you've changed the only one.

Answer (score 0):

If your changes to the php.ini and wp-config.php are saved correctly, check file permissions/ownership. Make sure your web user can make use of the file.

Comment: I've already checked, all files have read permissions for everyone and are in the same group as the web user.